# dialog checklist from mysql

Tags: bash, mysql, dialog

I have a todo list in mysql. I want to make it more interactive using `dialog`.

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t todo < <(mysql -uroot -hmy_host -p$my_pass -Dmy_db -BNe "select task from todo where complete=0;")

list=$(printf "'%s' off " "${todo[@]}")
```

If `echo "$list"` I get the desired result:

```
'test' off 'test two' off 'another test job' off
```

and if I plug that in manually, it works as expected.

But when I run dialog from a variable, the spaces in `'test two'` and `'another test job'` throws off my arguments and I get:

```
dialog --clear --no-items --checklist "todo list" 20 65 15 $(echo "$list")

Expected 2 arguments, found extra 1.
```

How do I get the values to properly populate the dialog checkbox from my bash script?

I have also tried code from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631873/how-to-generate-interactive-dialog-checklist-from-command-output

like so:

```
mapfile -t todo < <(mysql -uroot -hmy_host -p$my_pass -Dmy_db -BNe "select task from todo where complete=0;")

list=$(printf "'%s' off " "${todo[@]}")

cmd=$(dialog --stdout --no-items --separate-output --checklist "todo list" 20 65 15)

checklist=$("${cmd[@]}" "${list}")
```

But I get this error. And I don't know what it means:

```
Expected at least 20 tokens for --chec, have 4.
Use --help to list options.

./test.sh: line 13: : command not found   #this is from checklist=$("${cmd[@]}" "${list}")
```

I would have thought that mysql to dialog would be a very common task, but I haven't found any questions or answers on the subject. Should I give up and use php and browser?